# Soap bubble question, surface tension and excess pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, surface-tension, fluid-statics, bubbles

A soap bubble is blown slowly at the end of a tube by a pump supplying air at a constant rate. Draw a graph to represent the variation between the excess pressure inside the bubble with time.

Answer (score 1):

Excess pressure inside a soap bubble is 4T/R. Since air is blown at constant rate dV/dt is known. From rate change of volume calculate rate change of radius. Hence you get excess pressure in terms of time by putting R as f(t) in the formula.

Comment: Will it be dv/Dt= 4 pi r^2 Dr/Dt , then I'll put the relation in p=4T/r is it correct

Comment: @PhysiBoy I think you need to use a constant mass rate rather than a volume rate?

Comment: @Farcher Agreed, but it probably won't make a difference at these low pressures.

Comment: Correct @WetSavannaAnimal

Comment: Yes @Shub you are right